# Has WP and MU fully merged?

Tags: multisite

I'd heard that WP and MU were fully merging in WP 3.0.  Did this happen?  Is it now just a matter of installing the latest version of WP and turning on a multiple blog support switch...or is it more complicated than that?

Any insight anyone can provide would be most appreciated.

Eddie

Answer (score 6):

Yes, WP and WPMU have merged.  WPMU is now a feature called Multisite. Here are items on WordPress Answers tagged with *"multisite"*:

- [**Questions on WordPress Answers Tagged with "multisite"**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multisite)

Here's an article that shows you how to enable it:

- [**How to enable Multi-Site option in WordPress 3.0**](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-enable-multi-site-option-in-wordpress-3-0/)

Answer (score 4):

That is correct. As of Worpdress 3.0 the code bases have been merged.

Find more information here:

- http://www.clickonf5.org/wordpress/first-look-wordpress-30-mu-merge-settings-network-blogs/6699
- http://wpengineer.com/1953/wordpress-3-multisite-settings/

Answer (score 3):

And here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network
http://wpebooks.com/2010/09/how-to-enable-multisite-in-wordpress/

While it is a little easier to get running, the basic functionality is still the same. You need to ask your host if they support wildcard subdomains (if you want subdomains) and pretty permalinks is a requirement because it relies heavily on htaccess.